# What happens to Corda if R3 Liquidates

Tags: corda

What happens to Corda if R3 liquidates? And who are Corda's primary notaries that keep their main ledger decentralised? Is it possible for Corda to influence over historic ledger states and can change transactions to suit them?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such a thing as "the" Corda Network. R3 is a company that creates and licenses Corda software, which in itself is distributed with an open source license, but there is also an Enterprise version with additional proprietary features. Anyone can create their own Corda network using open source version of the software.

There is something called [the Corda Network Foundation](https://corda.network/). It is an independently-governed Corda network, which uses the software and some of the managed services provided by R3, but is not controlled by R3. You can read about its governance [here](https://corda.network/governance/index).

If R3 liquidates, two things are likely to happen:

1. The intellectual property rights to Corda are likely to be sold by the liquidators to someone. Most likely it'll be a foundation jointly governed by R3's largest clients.
2. The Corda Network Foundation will need to obtain managed services from somewhere else.